# Surface integral over the plane $x+y+z=2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Evaluate 
$$\iint_S x\;dy \times dz + y \; dz \times dx + z \; dx \times dy$$

where $S$ is the part of the plan $x+y+z=2$ in the first octant, with normal $n$ such that $n . (0,1,0) \geq 0$

My attempt:

Parametrizing the plane: $ \sigma(u,v) = (u,v,2-u-v) $ for $(u,v) \in [0,2] \times [0,2]$

The vector $(1,1,1)$ is normal to the surface and satisfies the condition. then, the integral will be

$$\int_0^2 \int_0^2 2 \; du \; dv = 8$$

The answer is $4$. What i did wrong?

Thanks in advance!

**@Edit** I see it is not $[0,2] \times [0,2]$, since it would give values of $z$ out of the domain.  Probably I should find a relation between u and v.

Answer (score 1):

That plane is not in the first octant for all of $[0,2]\times[0,2]$.  For instance, at $x=2,y=2$ we have $z=-2$ so this point is not in the first octant.

Comment: I've found the right region, thanks :)